# Regular Text Element is broken

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I'm using Typo3 Version 6.1.5 and I've installed the following extensions:

```
extension_buiilder
gridelements
realurl
```

The rest is only default stuff.

When I try to insert a "**Regular Text Element**" I get this broken view in every browser I've tested:

[image]

When I insert a "**Text & Images**" element on the other hand I get the normal RTE and stuff.

What could cause this?

Comment: Try this - uninstall one by one each of ext and try to inset text & images element (you will be sure which of plugin broke your installation). And remember - clear your cache

Comment: does gridelements have a static template? if yes, did you include it?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes it does, and it was included. Clearing the cache *and* removing all files from the cache folder manually solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clearing the cache **and** removing all files in the TYPO3 cache folder solved this issue.

Comment: I'll leave this question in case somebody else gets into the same trouble.